# Write some "if-statement"

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, grep

I want to write one script in "if-statement"

There are a lot of .html files in the ./simulations/ folder, and write end balance in the html files like this:

'end balance: 1000.00000000 (0.00%)'

'end balance: 19.21977440 (-98.08%)'

'end balance: 1135.80974233 (13.58%)'

I just want to find 'end balance: ....... (...%)'

if the end balance is 1000 or lower echo 'end balance 100 0r lwss', if it is higher, 'echo end balance bigger than 1000'.

like this:

`if [ "$(egrep -n 'end balance: [0-9.]' ./simulations/*.html)" -gt 1000 ]; then
echo ' end balance bigger than 1000 '
else
echo ' end balance less than 1000 '
fi`

Comment: What's the problem/error with this script?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reply masters

`EB=$(grep 'end balance:' ./simulations/*.html)
if [[ $(cut -d. -f1 <<<"$EB" | tr -cd [0-9]) -gt 1000 ]];
then
    echo "end balance bigger than 1000"
else
        echo "end balance less than 1000"
fi`

ı use this

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
egrep -n 'end balance: [0-9.]' <<< 'end balance: 1135.80974233 (13.58%)'
```

You will get:

```
1:end balance: 1135.80974233 (13.58%)
```

To compare number you must to have numbers on left and right, so I suggest below if-statement:

```
if (( $(grep -o 'end balance: [0-9]\{1,\}' ./simulations/*.html | awk '{print $3}') > 1000 ))
```

If you want do this for every file in ./simulations/ you use a loop:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in "$( ls -1 ./simulations/ | grep html$ )"
do
    if (( $(grep -o 'end balance: [0-9]\{1,\}' "$i" | awk '{print $3}') > 1000 ))
    then
        echo "end balance bigger than 1000"
    else
        echo "end balance less than 1000"
    fi
done
```

Below command:

```
grep -o 'end balance: [0-9]\{1,\}' <<< 'end balance: 1135.80974233 (13.58%)' | awk '{print $3}
```

Will print now:
1135

Answer (score 0):

Your condition fails because the output of the command substitution is not an integer. It also isn't being applied on a per-file basis.

In meta-code, what you're looking for is probably more along the lines of:

```
for every HTML file, loop
  Check the balance at the end of the file.
    If it's greater than 1000, do one thing,
    Otherwise, do something else.
end loop
```

In bash with grep, this might look something like:

```
for f in simulations/*.html; do
    if egrep -q 'end balance: (1000|[0-9]{3})\>' "$f"; then
        echo "$f: end balance > 1000"
    else
        echo "$f: end balance <= 1000 or missing"
    fi
done
```

If you wanted to pull the number out of the file for *numeric* comparison instead of using a regex, then this might work:

```
for f in simulations/*.html; do
    n="$(egrep -o 'end balance: [0-9]+' "$f" | grep -o '[0-9]*')"
    if [[ -z "$n" ]]; then
        echo "$f: no balance found"
    elif [[ $n -gt 1000 ]]; then
        echo "$f: end balance > 1000"
    else
        echo "$f: end balance <= 1000"
    fi
done
```

In both cases, you'll get a line of output for each HTML file that is processed.